# Filter activity inside ForEach activity

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with a Filter activity which is nested under a ForEach activity.

In order to reference the current item under ForEach activity, **item()** syntax can be used. Same goes for Filter activity.
However, as I have filter activity inside ForEach activity, how do I reference the ForEach activity and the Filter items separately, inside the Filter activity expression?

I came across some posts where the accepted answer was to use the function **items('name-of-my-foreach')**. However, Data Factory keeps return this error:

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The template validation failed: 'The workflow action 'FilterFilter1' at line '1 and column '61505' references the action '<name-of-my-foreach>' of type 'Http': only the actions of type 'foreach' are allowed to be referenced by 'repeatItems' or 'items' functions","target":"<name-of-pipeline>","details":null,"error":null}
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

NOTE: Set variable is not a viable option, because it would require sequential execution.

Comment: Hello , 
Can you please explain the use case here ? I am not able to follow "how do I reference the ForEach activity and the Filter items separately" . What do you mean by Filter item separately ? The Filter item is acting on the Items() which is feed in from the foreach loop . I think a little bit more context will help here .

Thanks 
Himamshu

Comment: Context is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bd5dbbe9-eb41-4252-ae58-5686f62ec37e/filter-activity-inside-for-each-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory). A ForEach within which you may use item() syntax, but when you want to have a filter activity within that for each, how do you differentiate between items from the filter and items from the ForEach?